# Legend does not appear in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is it possible to add a legend to this ggplot graph? Ideally the legend will list the different age ranges that are specified in my model below.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
df.year <- as.data.frame(2010:2032) 
  colnames(df.year) <- "Year"

ggplot(data = df.year, aes(x = Year)) +
  geom_line(data = cdc.fert.train, aes(y = `15-17 years`), color = "blue")+ 
  geom_line(data = cdc.fert.train, aes(y = `18-19 years`), color = "purple") +
  geom_line(data = cdc.fert.train, aes(y = `20–24 years`), color = "black") + 
  geom_line(data = cdc.fert.train, aes(y = `25–29 years`), color = "orange") + 
  geom_line(data = cdc.fert.train, aes(y = `30–34 years`), color = "red") + 
    geom_line(data = cdc.fert.train, aes(y = `35–39 years`), color = "pink") + 
    geom_line(data = cdc.fert.train, aes(y = `40–44 years`), color = "green")
```

Here is my data:

```
> dput(cdc.fert.train)
structure(list(Year = c(2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 
2017, 2018), `Crude Birth Rate` = c(13, 12.7, 12.6, 12.4, 12.5, 
12.4, 12.2, 11.8, 11.6), `15-17 years` = c(17.3, 15.4, 14.1, 
12.3, 10.9, 9.9, 8.8, 7.9, 7.2), `18-19 years` = c(58.2, 54.1, 
51.4, 47.1, 43.8, 40.7, 37.5, 35.1, 32.3), `20–24 years` = c(90, 
85.3, 83.1, 80.7, 79, 76.8, 73.8, 71, 68), `25–29 years` = c(108.3, 
107.2, 106.5, 105.5, 105.8, 104.3, 102.1, 98, 95.3), `30–34 years` = c(96.5, 
96.5, 97.3, 98, 100.8, 101.5, 102.7, 100.3, 99.7), `35–39 years` = c(45.9, 
47.2, 48.3, 49.3, 51, 51.8, 52.7, 52.3, 52.6), `40–44 years` = c(10.2, 
10.3, 10.4, 10.4, 10.6, 11, 11.4, 11.6, 11.8), `45-54 years` = c(0.7, 
0.7, 0.7, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9)), row.names = c(NA, -9L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: `ggplot2` works best when your data in in long format (i.e. a single column with fertility rate, and then one row per each combination of year and age group). Your data is currently in wide format (easier to do data entry in and to read for humans). Once you reshape it wider, you can just put `colour` as an argument in the main `aes()` and then add a single `geom_line()` layer (see langtang's solution below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the left side of the plot (you only provided data for that side), you can do the following:

1. pivot the data long
2. create a named list of colors
3. use `scale_color_manual`

```
fertility_long = cdc.fert.train %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = 3:10,names_to = "AgeGroup")

colors = c("blue","purple","black","orange","red","pink","green", "white")
names(colors) = unique(fertility_long$AgeGroup)

ggplot(fertility_long %>% filter(AgeGroup!="45-54 years"),aes(Year,value, color=AgeGroup)) + 
  geom_line(size=1.4)+
  scale_color_manual(values=colors) + 
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```